# Asp Mvc views with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two views and each view contains an link with data-action attribute to call jQuery function called toggle menu like this:

```
<div id="hide-menu" class="btn-header pull-right">
        <span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggleMenu" data-action="toggleMenu" title="Collapse Menu")">
                <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
toggleMenu: function () {
                        if (!$.root_.hasClass("menu-on-top")) {
                            $('html').toggleClass("hidden-menu-mobile-lock");
                            $.root_.toggleClass("hidden-menu");
                            $.root_.removeClass("minified");
                        } else if ($.root_.hasClass("menu-on-top") && $.root_.hasClass("mobile-view-activated")) {
                            $('html').toggleClass("hidden-menu-mobile-lock");
                            $.root_.toggleClass("hidden-menu");
                            $.root_.removeClass("minified");
                        }
                    }
```

one of the views  calls the function properly but the another doesn't, What is the possible reason for that??

Comment: They'll work differently if they're different.  You can use a side-by-side text comparison tool to determine the differences.   Start by removing everything except the menus to determine if there's some other issue.  Maybe there's something in the browser's console, eg if you've missed a `<script src=` on one of the pages.

Comment: I hope they are not partial views. By doing the process of elimination you can easily figure out the odd one which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact I haven't known the actual reason of the issue, maybe as Ramesh said in the comments was the problem.
I solved it by putting the function in the same document (not in another js file) and in the element, I have used onClick attribute to execute the function.

```
<div id="hide-menu" class="btn-header pull-right">
        <span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggleMenu" onclick="toggle()" title="Collapse Menu">
                <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
</div>

<script>
function toggle() {
                        if (!$.root_.hasClass("menu-on-top")) {
                            $('html').toggleClass("hidden-menu-mobile-lock");
                            $.root_.toggleClass("hidden-menu");
                            $.root_.removeClass("minified");
                        } else if ($.root_.hasClass("menu-on-top") && $.root_.hasClass("mobile-view-activated")) {
                            $('html').toggleClass("hidden-menu-mobile-lock");
                            $.root_.toggleClass("hidden-menu");
                            $.root_.removeClass("minified");
                        }
                    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.